# Pandas compare all DataFrame columns with eachother

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, comparison

How can I compare all columns in a DataFrame with each other, removing columns that are 'less than' other columns according to an arbitrary comparison function (where the comparison function is transitive).

e.g. If I have the DataFrame

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 4 1 1 3 6 2
1 4 2 2 7 2 6
2 4 3 3 3 6 2
3 4 8 3 7 2 6
```

and my function is "column A is < column B if A[i] < B[i] for all rows i", the result would be

```
  0 1 3 4
0 4 1 3 6
1 4 2 7 2
2 4 3 3 6
3 4 8 7 2
```

dropping column 2 as (4>1, 4>2, 4>3, 4>3) and column 5 as (3>2, 7>6, 3>2, 7>6).

My initial/obvious-but-slow approach is that this can be done in n^2 time with (pseudo code; I haven't done much Pandas programming before... answers with real code would be appreciated)

```
for i in range(0, n):
  for j in range(0, n):
    if my_less_than_function(col(i), col(j)):
      # i < j
      drop col(i)
```

If the less than function is transitive I could also remember which columns I've already dropped and skip them when iterating i and j. I could also iterate j in range(i + 1, n) if my comparison function returned (-1, 0, 1) for (less, equal, more) instead of (true, false) for (less, equal or more)

Note the comparison function may not be pairwise by row e.g. it could be sum(col A) < sum(col B) or number_of_primes_in(col A) < number_of_primes_in(col B)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [4, 1, 1, 3, 6, 2],
        [4, 2, 2, 7, 2, 6],
        [4, 3, 3, 3, 6, 2],
        [4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6]
    ], columns=list('abcdef'))

print(df)

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  4  1  1  3  6  2
1  4  2  2  7  2  6
2  4  3  3  3  6  2
3  4  8  3  7  2  6
```

---

***`numpy` broadcasting***

For your definition of `less_than` we can use `numpy`

```
v = df.values
lt = pd.DataFrame((v.T[:, None] < v.T).all(-1), df.columns, df.columns)

print(lt)

       a      b      c      d      e      f
a  False  False  False  False  False  False
b  False  False  False  False  False  False
c   True  False  False  False  False  False
d  False  False  False  False  False  False
e  False  False  False  False  False  False
f  False  False  False   True  False  False
```

---

You can pull out specific columns in the following way:

***all columns that are `>= 'f'`***

```
df.loc[:, lt.loc['f']]

   d
0  3
1  7
2  3
3  7
```

***all columns that `< 'f'`***

```
df.loc[:, ~lt.loc['f']]

   a  b  c  e  f
0  4  1  1  6  2
1  4  2  2  2  6
2  4  3  3  6  2
3  4  8  3  2  6
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
In [278]: df
Out[278]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  4  1  1  3  6  2
1  4  2  2  7  2  6
2  4  3  3  3  6  2
3  4  8  3  7  2  6

In [279]: cols2drop = [col for col in df.columns if df.T.gt(df[col]).all(1).any()]

In [280]: cols2drop
Out[280]: [2, 5]

In [282]: df = df.drop(cols2drop, 1)

In [283]: df
Out[283]:
   0  1  3  4
0  4  1  3  6
1  4  2  7  2
2  4  3  3  6
3  4  8  7  2
```

Explanation:

```
In [286]: df.T.gt(df[2])
Out[286]:
       0      1      2      3
0   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3   True   True  False   True
4   True  False   True  False
5   True   True  False   True

In [287]: df.T.gt(df[2]).all(1)
Out[287]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

In [288]: df.T.gt(df[2]).all(1).any()
Out[288]: True
```